# How to control the fading size in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a fading using `tikzfadingfrompicture`, but I cannot understand how TikZ computes the size of the fading. I assumed that TikZ calculates the bounding box of the image to fade, and then stretches the fading-picture to match its bounding box with the bounding box of the image, but the following code snippet proves I am wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade frame]
  \draw[transparent!0,step=0.2cm] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [black!20] (-2,-2) rectangle (7,7);
  \pattern [pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=black!30] (-2,-2)
  rectangle (7,7);
  \draw[step=0.5cm,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (7,7);
  \fill [path fading=fade frame,red] (-2,-2) rectangle (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The picture I get has 9 squares, and not 10 as I would expect (because the original grid in the fading is 2cm wide and has a step=0.2cm).  Am I doing something wrong?  How can I have TikZ use the whole fading-picture?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but why would you expect 10? BTW, can you add `\usetikzlibrary{fadings},\usetikzlibrary{patterns}` to your code as well as the `\begin{document},end{document}` etc. to make it a minimal working example. It makes it easier to copy and paste.

Comment: @percusse: I expect 10 boxes because I draw a 2cm wide grid with step=0.2cm.  Here is the complete code:

Comment: @Marco : Ouch. You get n division not n-1 of course :) So, I have added `fit fading = false` option in the last fill command and saw that it is indeed creating a 10x10 block. But stretching this guide seems to be your problem.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you for the comment on the fit fading=false.  Indeed, my question is really how TikZ computes the stretching when using a fading (see second sentence in my original question).

Comment: @Marco: Yep, today I am not so bright as you can tell :) I have no idea why but `step=1.75mm` works. I guess there is an additional undocumented part to this.

Comment: @percusse: Interesting... However, I am now even more puzzled: the number of boxes shown is somewhat independent of the size of the grid: for example using `\draw[transparent!0,step=0.2cm] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);` does not make a difference wrt the code I wrote in the original question.

Comment: @Marco: indeed! Moreover, as long as you keep your rectangle aspect ratio the shading is the same pattern i.e. it does not matter if the rectangle is huge or tiny always the same shading(I use QTikz to play around with it).  What is also funny is that if you change `\draw[transparent!0,step=0.2cm] (0,0) grid (1,1);` the pattern seems to work.

Comment: @Marco: In fact if you just use `\draw[transparent!0,step=0.2cm] (0,0) grid (1,1);` gives exactly what you wanted, but obviously, does not qualify as an answer. What I am puzzled the most is that the pattern seems to agree in the center of the figure but not towards the corners.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you again for pointing this.  I start to think that either there is a bug in pgf/TikZ...  If this is not solved perhaps I should contact the developers.

Comment: @percusse: Since you did a fair bit of experimenting for this question, I thought you might like to know that I've tried to answer it.  (Marco will get an automatic notification but you won't, unless you've favourited this question.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following is 50% experiment, 50% trying to read the TikZ code, and 100% guesswork.

It appears that when TikZ/PGF uses a path as a fading then it doesn't use the *whole* path.  Indeed, this is pretty clear from the following comment in the file `pgfcoretransparency.code.tex`:

```
% This command works a bit like \pgfshadepath. "Works a bit like"
% means the following: The masks's original size should
% completely cover the area between (0,0) and (100bp,100bp). The
% mask is then rescaled so that it completely covers the path.
```

The key part is that bit about the "masks's [sic] original size".  This indicates that when specifying a fading from a picture (or path) then the actual mask used is whatever lies in a certain box, not the entire picture.  (One can dispute whether or not this is the Right Thing to Do, but this isn't the place for that.)

**However** the rectangle suggested in the above comment does not appear to be the right one.  (This is where the experiments come in.)  What appears to happen is that the segment used is that from the centre of the picture with size 50bp.  That is, find the centre of the picture and plonk a square of side length 50bp so that its centre is at the centre of the picture.

To see that this is the case, we can consider the example given in the aforementioned file:

```
 \pgfdeclarefading{fade right}
 {\tikz[left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
    (0,0) rectangle (100bp,100bp);}
```

This would appear to define a rectangular shading from full colour at the left to fully transparent at the right.  The following code shows that this isn't what happens.  Indeed, to get that result we have to cut the size down to `50bp`:

[image: fadings]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19596/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarefading{test fading b}
 {\tikz
    \fill[left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100] (0,0) rectangle (50bp,50bp);}

\pgfdeclarefading{test fading a}
 {\tikz
    \fill[left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100] (0,0) rectangle (100bp,100bp);}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\fill[gray!50] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
\filldraw[path fading=test fading a,fill=purple] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\filldraw[path fading=test fading b,fill=purple] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Further experimenting does show that the section of the fading used is the centre of the given picture.

Now we can see what goes wrong with your fading.  If we draw the actual picture (with the colours changed so that we can see them) and superimpose a square of size `50bp` then we can see why the fading produced is only 9 squares.

[image: grid fading]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19596/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
  \draw[black,step=0.2cm] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\draw[red] (-25bp,-25bp) rectangle (25bp,25bp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The `scale`s in all these are just to get decent sized images; they make no actual difference.)

This corresponds with what we get when we compile your code:

[image: original picture]

So the solution is to draw the original fading in a box of side length `50bp`.  This then gives the desired outcome.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19596/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade frame]
  \draw[transparent!0,step=5bp] (0,0) grid (50bp,50bp);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [black!20] (-2,-2) rectangle (7,7);
  \pattern [pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=black!30] (-2,-2)
  rectangle (7,7);
  \draw[step=0.5cm,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (7,7);
  \fill [path fading=fade frame,red] (-2,-2) rectangle (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: grid with 10 squares]

(The more I think about this, the more I can see that there is a sort of logic to having it work this way.  But reasonable or not, this appears to be undocumented and *that* is certainly less than ideal!)

Comment: Well, I will take some time for me to digest this. But nevertheless, thanks a lot for relieving some of the pain :)