# TikZ: Fading text too wide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

In the code below, I want to produce a similar effect to the example on page 359 of the PGF manual.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%\documentclass[tikz,preview]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    margin = 0mm,
    paperwidth = 8cm,
    paperheight = 2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgbonum,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}


\begin{document}
%
\tikzset{font = {\fontsize{20}{22}\selectfont} }
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = latexnica]
    \node[text=transparent!20] at (0,0) {Establishmentless};% This text is too wide!
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node[
%%      inner sep = 1pt,
%       path fading = latexnica,
%       text = transparent,
%       top color = blue!85,
%       bottom color = orange!90
%   ] at (0,0) {Establishmentless};
    \node[text = white] (e) at (0,0) {Establishmentless};
    \shade[
        path fading = latexnica,
        fit fading = true,
        top color = blue!85,
        bottom color = orange!90
        ] (e.south west) rectangle (e.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

I obtain the attached image; as I commented in the code, the text of the fading (shading?) path is too wide; what I want is to have a rectangle with top blue part, bottom orange part and a faded text that reveals these colours. As you can see, I tried it using both a node and a rectangle of the same side (additionally, the key `text = transparent` shows the text in black. I'd like to understand why; in, so in the final picture I intend to use `text = white`).

How can I fit the text of the fading picture to the one I have below it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `fit fading` is the key. So PGF will do some rescaling to make sure that things don't go out of bounds. You need to read the manual carefully to understand how the rescaling works.

Comment: You only need to set `fit fading=false`. (I find the manual a bit confusing here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post is written under the assumption that you do not want to simply use `fit fading=false`. I am largely repeating [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27544/194703). If you set `fit fading` to `true`, then Ti*k*Z will use `\pgfsetfadingforcurrentpath` (or `\pgfsetfadingforcurrentpathstroked` if the path has a stroked curve). The pgfmanual v3.1.5 says about this option on p. 1202

[image]

However, this is *not* the case. Rather, as discovered in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27544/194703), the box is really `50pt` times `50pt` large. Indeed, if we rescale the node underlying the `latexnica` fading to have these dimensions, the correct result is obtained.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%\documentclass[tikz,preview]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    margin = 0mm,
    paperwidth = 8cm,
    paperheight = 2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgbonum,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newsavebox\fadbox

\begin{document}
%
\tikzset{font ={\fontsize{20}{22}\selectfont}}
\savebox\fadbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {Establishmentless};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = latexnica]
    \node[text=transparent!20,xscale=50pt/\wd\fadbox,yscale=50pt/\ht\fadbox] 
    at (0,0) {Establishmentless};% 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node[
%%      inner sep = 1pt,
%       path fading = latexnica,
%       text = transparent,
%       top color = blue!85,
%       bottom color = orange!90
%   ] at (0,0) {Establishmentless};
    \node[text = white] (e) at (0,0) {Establishmentless};
    \shade[
        path fading = latexnica,
        fit fading = true,
        top color = blue!85,
        bottom color = orange!90
        ] (e.south west) rectangle (e.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

So I think that there could be an issue, which got reported [here](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/868), where you can also find some technical details that IMHO support the conjecture of a slight error in the manual.

Comment: I do not recommend using `fadings`.  There are a lot of buggy viewers.

Comment: As always, Mr. Cat, quite useful! Thanks!